# button makes one row active others inactive

Tags: php, sql, pdo

This status(active 1 /inactive 0) button makes any individual record active/inactive.
I need to change it so that when clicked it makes the that record active and all others inactive by changing tbladdress_status db variable.

```
if (isset($_GET['tbladdress_status'])) {
    if ($_GET['tbladdress_status']=="ok") { 
        $statusupdate=$db->prepare("UPDATE tbl_address SET          
            tbladdress_status=:tbladdress_status
            WHERE tbladdress_id={$_GET['tbladdress_id']}                
            ");     
        $update=$statusupdate->execute(array(   
            'tbladdress_status' => $_GET['activestatus']
            )); 
        if ($update) {              
            Header("Location:../../front-address-all.php?status=ok");   
        } else {    
            Header("Location:../../front-address-all.php?status=no");
        }   
    }
}
```

---

```
<?php 
if ($pulladdress['tbladdress_status']==1) { ?>
<a href="nedmin/netting/pdo-process.php?tbladdress_id=<?php echo $pulladdress['tbladdress_id'] ?>&activestatus=0&tbladdress_status=ok"><button class="btn btn-success btn-xs"><?php echo _ACTIVE; ?></button>
<?php } elseif($pulladdress['tbladdress_status']==0) {?>
<a href="nedmin/netting/pdo-process.php?tbladdress_id=<?php echo $pulladdress['tbladdress_id'] ?>&activestatus=1&tbladdress_status=ok"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><?php echo _PASSIVE; ?></button>                
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Means, onclick of button you want to hide the current button and display another button.

Comment: Hi, in the active address column there will be only one row that says "active", other rows will say "inactive", if you click another row then that row will be active and others will be inactive.

Comment: You can do it, by using jquery and javascript.

Comment: What keeps you from adjusting the logic? Also, be warned that your code is widely open for SQL injection (in the `WHERE`  clause)

Comment: Ref:sql injection, doesnt PREPARE statement prevent injection? Im supposedly using PDO without knowing much.